# How can I make a list of files like in SharePoint with Drupal 7?

Tags: sharepoint, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-7

I was using SharePoint 2007 but because costs I ended up using Drupal 7 to substitute my site that I had with SharePoint.
I'm new using Drupal and I would like make a list of uploaded files, keep them inside of carpets, just like the SharePoint lists.

Is there any Drupal module that I can use for this?? or How can I make the module by myself??

Comment: are you in anyway involving SharePoint in this or do you simply want the same styling as SharePoint have?

Comment: Look into [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: No, I'm not involving SharePoint. I just want the same styling and functionality as in SharePoint. I looked into Views but is confusing for me,, can you guide me to the right direction??

Answer (score 0):

If you hang with the swedish accent, these video tutorials are pretty comprehensive:
[Taming the Beast: Learn Views with NodeOne](http://nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone)

Comment: Thank you. Those videos are very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Drupal's Filedepot, https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot,  module will do.

From the project page: "The filedepot module is full featured Document Management module that has a google docs like feel. It fulfills the need for an integrated file management module supporting role and user based security. Documents can be saved outside the Drupal public directory to protect documents for safe access and distribution."